# как построить график двух функций по таблице

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, matplotlib

Есть некоторая таблица экспериментальных данных в формате csv. Я её импортирую следующим образом:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
>>> df
    'Set'     'Rx'     'Traffic'     'Modulation'
0   -67.0   -64.35         15.00     '64-QAM 2/3'
1   -68.0   -65.35         15.00     '16-QAM 3/4'
2   -69.0   -66.85         14.78     '64-QAM 2/3'
3   -70.0   -67.60         15.42     '64-QAM 2/3'
4   -71.0   -68.85         15.04     '64-QAM 2/3'
5   -72.0   -70.35         15.04     '16-QAM 3/4'
6   -73.0   -70.85         15.04     '16-QAM 3/4'
7   -74.0   -71.35         15.28     '16-QAM 3/4'
8   -75.0   -72.60         12.35     '64-QAM 2/3'
9   -76.0   -73.10         11.38     '16-QAM 3/4'
10  -77.0   -74.60         11.64     '16-QAM 3/4'
11  -78.0   -75.60          7.76     '16-QAM 1/2'
12  -79.0   -76.85          7.76     '16-QAM 1/2'
13  -80.0   -77.85          7.52     '16-QAM 1/2'
14  -81.0   -79.35          5.85       'QPSK 3/4'
```

Теперь я хочу построить график, в котором в качестве значений Х используется колонка 'Set'. На этом графике я хочу увидеть **две**(!) кривые:

- Y1: 'Rx'
- Y2: 'Traffic'

Как такое можно сделать с помощью *matplotlib.pyplot*? Нашёл руководство ([Pandas](https://khashtamov.com/ru/pandas-introduction/)), где первым шагом рекомендуют выделить колонку из таблицы, как-то так:

```
df = pd.read_csv('apple.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
new_sample_df = df.loc['2012-Feb':'2017-Feb', ['Close']]
```

Но у меня первый индекс датафрейма числовой и я никак не могу выбрать интересующую меня колонку:

```
new_sample_df = df.iloc[0:14, ['Rx']]
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Но даже, если я сумею это как-то сделать, то как передать в функцию рисования два (!) значения Y для каждой точки по Х?
Попробовал оба предложенных варианта. Не получается :-( Что бы исключить неясности, привожу сам CSV файл:

```
'Set,Rx','Traffic','Modulation'
-67.00, -64.35,    15.00,   '64-QAM 2/3'
-68.00, -65.35,    15.00,   '16-QAM 3/4'
-69.00, -66.85,    14.78,   '64-QAM 2/3'
-70.00, -67.60,    15.42,   '64-QAM 2/3'
-71.00, -68.85,    15.04,   '64-QAM 2/3'
-72.00, -70.35,    15.04,   '16-QAM 3/4'
-73.00, -70.85,    15.04,   '16-QAM 3/4'
-74.00, -71.35,    15.28,   '16-QAM 3/4'
-75.00, -72.60,    12.35,   '64-QAM 2/3'
-76.00, -73.10,    11.38,   '16-QAM 3/4'
-77.00, -74.60,    11.64,   '16-QAM 3/4'
-78.00, -75.60,     7.76,   '16-QAM 1/2'
-79.00, -76.85,     7.76,   '16-QAM 1/2'
-80.00, -77.85,     7.52,   '16-QAM 1/2'
-81.00, -79.35,     5.85,     'QPSK 3/4'
```

И текст программулины, которую пытаюсь выполнить, с двумя закомментированными вариантами:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r'data.csv', quotechar="'")
#1 df.set_index('Set')[['Rx','Traffic']].plot(legend=True, grid=True)
#2 df.set_index("'Set'")[["'Rx'","'Traffic'"]].plot(legend=True, grid=True)
```

Если раскомментировать #1, то выдаётся сообщение:

```
KeyError: 'Set'
```

Если раскомментировать #2, то сообщение соответственно меняется:

```
KeyError: "'Set'"
```

Может быть всё дело в том, что меня третий питон, а примеры - для второго?

Comment: Нашёл ошибку!
В файле данных был пропущен апостроф в одном месте.
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: CSV надо исправить: 'Set,Rx' —> 'Set','Rx'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы правильно прочитать CSV, где значения и имена столбцов обрамлены кавычками следует использовать параметр `quotechar=...`:

```
In [26]: df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\data.csv', quotechar="'")

In [27]: df
Out[27]:
     Set     Rx  Traffic  Modulation
0  -67.0 -64.35    15.00  64-QAM 2/3
1  -68.0 -65.35    15.00  16-QAM 3/4
2  -69.0 -66.85    14.78  64-QAM 2/3
3  -70.0 -67.60    15.42  64-QAM 2/3
4  -71.0 -68.85    15.04  64-QAM 2/3
5  -72.0 -70.35    15.04  16-QAM 3/4
6  -73.0 -70.85    15.04  16-QAM 3/4
7  -74.0 -71.35    15.28  16-QAM 3/4
8  -75.0 -72.60    12.35  64-QAM 2/3
9  -76.0 -73.10    11.38  16-QAM 3/4
10 -77.0 -74.60    11.64  16-QAM 3/4
11 -78.0 -75.60     7.76  16-QAM 1/2
12 -79.0 -76.85     7.76  16-QAM 1/2
13 -80.0 -77.85     7.52  16-QAM 1/2
14 -81.0 -79.35     5.85    QPSK 3/4

In [28]: df.columns
Out[28]: Index(['Set', 'Rx', 'Traffic', 'Modulation'], dtype='object')
```

после этого построить график можно так:

```
df.set_index('Set')[['Rx','Traffic']].plot(legend=True, grid=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пример CSV файла:

```
'Set','Rx','Traffic','Modulation'
-67.0,-64.35,15.0,'64-QAM 2/3'
-68.0,-65.35,15.0,'16-QAM 3/4'
-69.0,-66.85,14.78,'64-QAM 2/3'
-70.0,-67.6,15.42,'64-QAM 2/3'
-71.0,-68.85,15.04,'64-QAM 2/3'
-72.0,-70.35,15.04,'16-QAM 3/4'
-73.0,-70.85,15.04,'16-QAM 3/4'
-74.0,-71.35,15.28,'16-QAM 3/4'
-75.0,-72.6,12.35,'64-QAM 2/3'
-76.0,-73.1,11.38,'16-QAM 3/4'
-77.0,-74.6,11.64,'16-QAM 3/4'
-78.0,-75.6,7.76,'16-QAM 1/2'
-79.0,-76.85,7.76,'16-QAM 1/2'
-80.0,-77.85,7.52,'16-QAM 1/2'
-81.0,-79.35,5.85,'QPSK 3/4'
```

Comment: Я дополнил свой вопрос текстами программы и данных, что бы не было никаких неясностей. Посмотрите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

```
df.set_index("'Set'")[["'Rx'","'Traffic'"]].plot(legend=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не работает :-( В программе 9 строк, включая две пустые и банг и ничего не могу понять! Выдаёт: * File "./plot_data.py", line 9, in <module>, KeyError: 'Set'* Вот весь текст:

*#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col='Set')
df = df.sort_index()
df.set_index('Set')[['Rx','Traffic']].plot(legend=True)*

Comment: у вас имена столбцов обрамлены одиночными кавычками - я исправил ответ... Можете привести первые 15-20 строк вашего CSV в вопросе (как он есть)?